# Label load with "weird characters" from server

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, web-services, cocoa-touch

I have a label in a view which loads a plain text file and displays the content, but it displays weird characters not located in the .txt file along with the real content.

The text file has one line in it : "Update Submitted"

This is what it looks like on the actual device itself.

[image]
As you can see,  the "Update Submitted" label has 2 weird characters in front of it.

I'm using this code :

```
content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
URLWithString:@"http://samguichelaar.com/soadstatus.txt"] encoding: 1 error: NULL];
Label1.text = content;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using ASCII encoding. Switch to UTF8 encoding:

```
URLWithString:@"http://samguichelaar.com/soadstatus.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL]
```

Also, you should use the Apple provided constants for any string encoding in case Apple ever decides they want to change the value associated with any of the constants:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Search for NSStringEncoding

Answer (score 2):

Set the encoding - **NSUTF8StringEncoding**

```
content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
URLWithString:@"http://samguichelaar.com/soadstatus.txt"] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL];
Label1.text = content;
```